# Openstack db sync error

Tags: openstack-nova

I issue the nova manage db sync command and when i issue I'm facing the problem,

```
TRACE nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 56, in __init__
2015-01-11 00:31:29 TRACE nova     self.port = int(port)
2015-01-11 00:31:29 TRACE nova ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Can you suggest the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The probelm was because I din't give any port number followed by the colon in the nova.conf file for the sql connetion. I removed the colon and is working fine now.